# .htaccess RewriteRule : add dash(-) to my domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want modify my URLs from:

```
domain/content.php?page=x
```

To:

```
domain/x-y
```

I put this code in my file `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ content.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: so you want it to be `domain/content.php?page=x-y`? Can you describe your question better and provide more exact examples to what you're trying to achieve? [You can click here to edit your question and update it with more information](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22306433/edit)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `y` part of the URL, you don't need to create a grouping that matches it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)- /content.php?page=$1 [L]
```